# "cannot find entry file in any of the roots" issue in React Navigation redux example

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I am getting this error in the IOS simulator:

```
cannot find entry file "examples/ReduxExample/index.js" in any of the root.
```

And in the terminal:

```
Loading dependency graph...
React packager ready.

Loading dependency graph, done.
error: bundling: Error
    at DependencyGraph._getAbsolutePath (/Users/greg_work/temp/react_native_temp/ReduxExample/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/index.js:285:11)
    at load.then (/Users/greg_work/temp/react_native_temp/ReduxExample/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/index.js:228:28)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
Bundling `examples/ReduxExample/index.js`  0.0% (0/1), failed.
Launching Dev Tools...
error: bundling: Error
    at DependencyGraph._getAbsolutePath (/Users/greg_work/temp/react_native_temp/ReduxExample/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/index.js:285:11)
    at load.then (/Users/greg_work/temp/react_native_temp/ReduxExample/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/index.js:228:28)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
Bundling `examples/ReduxExample/index.js`  0.0% (0/1), failed.
```

This is when trying to run the React Navigation redux example here:  https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/tree/master/examples/ReduxExample.

I basically:

1. Downloaded the ZIP for the github project
2. Extracted the Redux Example folder and copied it across to another area
3. run "npm install"
4. react-native run-ios

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried like this

```
 cd examples/NavigationPlayground or Redux Example
    npm install
    cd ../..
    npm start

    # In a seperate terminal tab:
    npm run run-playground-android
    # OR:
    npm run run-playground-ios
```

Comment: yes - I've had some issues here too.  However I found one example posted here that I got running.... https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/1229